# Excel VBA - Dragging formulas and formatting down after inserting new rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some code that adds a variable number of rows to an existing table in an Excel form, I need some code that will drag the cell formatting and formulas in B36:L36 down across the newly inserted rows.

The macro will always add new lines starting at row 37, but the number of rows it adds is variable, so the code needs to just copy formatting (columns B & C are merged, then are are formulas in columns H, J & L.

Edit - code for adding rows as follows. This takes a count from the BRF Macro sheet and if it's higher than 20 adds additional sheet rows.

```
If (Workbooks(ProjectCostReport).Worksheets("BRF Macro").Range("I1") > 20) Then

Dim rowstoadd As Integer
rowstoadd = Workbooks(ProjectCostReport).Worksheets("BRF Macro").Range("i1") - 20


Workbooks("NEW UKOTC 2020 BRF.xlsx").Worksheets("T&M BRF").Rows("37:" & 37 + rowstoadd).Insert
```

[Excel table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tom7Y.png)

Comment: Can you show the code, where you add the rows?

Comment: there is a Range.FillDown method that will fill down a formula already in the range to the rest of the cells below it.